# Populating Bootstrap modal w/ sql from table row click

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've been working on this all week and finally gave up and decided to ask outright.  What I have is a list of open jobs in a bootstrap table that is populated via a mysql query.  When a row is clicked, a model appears showing the details of the job.  The UI works flawlessly, but now that I've tried to get the correct data to show in the modal, I'm at a loss.

From what I've read, the solution seems to be in using AJAX, which I have zero experience with.  I can't seem to figure out from reading through other solutions and tutorials if I need my modal information, sql query, or both to be on a separate page.  Here is my initial code:

**jobs.php**

```
<table class="table table-hover" data-link="row">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Job #</th>

            <th>Quote #</th>

            <th>Date Started</th>

            <th>Customer Name</th>

            <th>Description</th>

            <th>Amount</th>

            <th>Date Completed</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobs)) {
                    // Print out the contents of the entry
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobModal" ></a>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['quote'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['started'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['customer'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>$' . $row['amt'] . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Modal** - Also in jobs.php (ignore the placeholders, they will be replaced with php variables when I get things working)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="jobModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="jobModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="jobModalLabel"><strong>Job <?php echo $row['id']; ?></strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            Quote #
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            PO # 1234567
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            Status: In Progress
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
                            Customer Name
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <br/>
                            Started: 03/01/2015
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <br/>
                            Completed:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 text-right">
                            Primary Contact
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                            <strong>PUMP SPECS</strong><br/><br/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                            <strong>MOTOR SPECS</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            Mfg: Taco
                            <br/><br/>
                            Size: 6x4
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            Mod: 54654856daf5
                            <br/><br/>
                            S/N: 54654856daf5
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 border-left">
                            Mfg: Baldor
                            <br/><br/>
                            Frame: 215T
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            HP: 50
                            <br/><br/>
                            Encl: TEFC
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            RPM: 1800
                            <br/><br/>
                            Volts: 100
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-6 border-left">
                        <br/>
                        Amps: 240/360
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <br/>
                        S/N: 54654856daf5
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <strong>Job Description:</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Job</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

From this point, is there anyway I can get the id to come through on the modal side so I can fill in the rest of the information using php like I did with the original table?  If I do need to use ajax, what is the correct way to go about doing so?

Comment: so when you click on the id the modal should pop up with the data for only that id?

Comment: If you want to save changes in the modal, you should add a `form` that begins before the first `input` and end after the `button`, that by the way should be `type="submit"` if you want to submit the form..

Comment: Correct, the modal should pop up with only the data for that id.  No changes need to be made to the data in the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

If you try this then?

TABLE TO OPEN MODALS

```
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobs)) {
        // Print out the contents of the entry
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#jobModal'.$row['id'].'" >Click here to edit</a>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['quote'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['started'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['customer'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>$' . $row['amt'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
```

MODALS

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($jobs)) { ?>
    <div class="modal fade" id="jobModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="jobModalLabel<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="jobModalLabel<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><strong>Job <?php echo $row['id']; ?></strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit Job</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The `data-target` in the link for the modal search for the ID (that needs to be unique), therefore, you should set the `$row['id']` in the modal id (and data-target) to specify which modal you want to open. In the end, you will have one modal/row from the database. If there are a lot of rows, the page will take a lot of time to load. In that case, you should use `AJAX`. Remember that the modals are still there, but hidden.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, but I still can't quite get it right.  When I copy your code, it tells me there is an error with the table set line you gave.  The quotes around id seem to be causing some issue, and I'm getting the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I managed to find a solution in simply pulling the modal data from a separate page, which I populated by appending the job id to the url and using a get variable.  However, I really think your answer would have worked, and it was exactly what I was looking for when I posted.  Thank you for all your help.

Comment: PS: also not optimum, if table has 1000 rows, will generate 1000 modals? no way, i'm learning data binding -like knockoutjs- and you also should go that way

Comment: @Enrique, if you have 1000 rows, you could make an easy page-function using SQL `limit`, or you can get the data when the user asks for the modal. I usually prefer to limit the rows depending on how often the modals are used and also how important it is to show all rows on the same page. If you are looking for a specific row, combine the page-function with an easy search function using SQL aswell? Less work and probably easier to read the code.

Comment: @SebastianHallin you're right, didn't think of it, it was a cold comment I did without processing before :)